# Why is it only one picture shows up in the imageArray?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3

I'm using collectionview here, but everything is ok. It's just that only the "c" picture shows up in my imageArray.

```
let ig:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    imageArray = [b","a","c")]
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }   
    return imageView
 }()
func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    addSubview(statusImageView)
    addSubview(ig)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]-4-|", views: ig)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: ig)   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code the entire for loop executes before you return anythg.... So the image for the imageview which you return is overwritten with the next one even before you return it.... Eventually the last image in the array being assigned to the imageview is returned to the variable which calls the function.... Your logic is mistaken there...